# How many ways exist to group n ordered elements?

Tags: combinatorics

I am currently thinking about on-line handwriting recognition of mathematical formulas. On-line means that I get the information how the user writes.

Assuming that the user writes one symbol after another, I can break the task of formula recognition into many tasks of symbol reconition. But I still need to get to know which strokes form one symbol.

### Example

[image]

This example has 10 strokes and 7 symbols:

- The first stroke (red) is one symbol (`\sum`)
- The second and third stroke is one symbol (`i`)
- ...

### Question

But how many groupings could there possibly be?

### My approach

I thought of it this way:

I call the function I am searching $g: \mathbb{N}_{> 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}_{> 0}$.

Obviously, $g(1) = 1$.

Let's display strokes with `o` and groups with `|`. Lets say the number of strokes is $n$.

- $n = 2$: `oo` or `o|o` $\Rightarrow g(2) = 1+g(1)=2$
- $n = 3$: `ooo` or `o|X` (possiblities for 2) or `oo|o` $\Rightarrow g(3) = 1+g(2)+g(1) = 4$
- $n = 4$: `oooo` or `o|X` (possiblities for 3) or `oo|X` (possibilites for 2) or `ooo|o` $\Rightarrow g(4) = 1+g(3)+g(2)+g(1) = 8$

At this point I think I can see a pattern:

$$g(n) = 1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} g(i) =2^{n-1}$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your approach does indeed have $2^{n-1}$ groupings, because there are $n-1$ possible places to insert a vertical spacer, and each of these may be done, or not, independently.
2. Your approach does not include the possibility that we draw the two strokes for "=" nonconsecutively.  To count those, we need [Bell numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_numbers).

Comment: Ah, so I can simply ignore the `o` and think of the spaces where I can insert the delimiter `|`. This is a binary number (either the delimiter is there or not) and so it is $2^{n-1}$. Thanks! Is there also such a simple formula when I only have symbols with a maximum of $m$ strokes?

Comment: Not really, you want ${n-1\choose 0}+{n-1\choose 1}+\cdots+{n-1\choose m}$.  This sum is nice ($2^{n-1}$) only when $m=n-1$.